# Android JSP page handler

Tags: android

I want to upload file using to a JSP page through android. If any one know how to implement JSP handler in android please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming to your question, there are quite a lot of examples out in the community as well as in the web. To start with, check some of them below.

[File upload from Android](http://www.codicode.com/art/upload_files_from_android_to_a_w.aspx)

[Similar Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551431/upload-image-from-android-to-java-servlet-and-save-it)